# SWI-Prolog sort predicate not working

Tags: prolog

I just made up a program, doing following task: "Get elements, which values are equal to their indexes".

Here is the code:

```
% get element's index
get_index([Element|_], Element, 0).
get_index([_|T], Element, Index) :-
    get_index(T, Element, Index1),
    Index is Index1+1.

index_equals_to_element(List, List2) :-
    member(X, List),
    get_index(List, X, Index),
    Index =:= X,
    append([], [X], List2).
```

It works pretty well. But there is one problem. For list **[0, 3, 2, 4, 0]** my predicate `index_equals_to_element` returns **[0, 2, 0]**.

Okay, let it happen. But when I'm trying to output only unique elements, I'm getting the same list without any changes. Example:

```
?- index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], List).
% Outputs [0, 2, 0]

?- sort(List, List2).
% Outputs [0, 2, 0] either, when expected [0, 2]
```

It's very strange for me, because this works fine:

```
?- sort([0, 2, 1, 0], List).
% Outputs [0, 1, 2].
```

Why `sort` doesn't work only with the list, generated by my predicate?

Comment: The call to `append/3` is pointless. Appending an empty list with any list results in the same list. I.e. `append([], List, List)` is always true assuming the common definition of the `append/3` predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], List).` doesn't output `[0, 2, 0]` as you claim, but gives three answers `[0]`, `[2]` and `[0]`:

```
?- index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], List).
List = [0] ;
List = [2] ;
List = [0] ;
false.
```

You can use `findall` to get what you want:

```
?- findall(X, index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], [X]), List).
List = [0, 2, 0].
```

*Update.* Here is what I think a better implementation of `index_equals_to_element/2`:

```
index_equals_to_element(List, List2) :-
    index_equals_to_element(List, 0, List2).

index_equals_to_element([], _, []).
index_equals_to_element([X | Rest], I, Rest2) :-
    Inext is I + 1,
    index_equals_to_element(Rest, Inext, NewRest),
    ( X =:= I ->
        Rest2 = [X | NewRest]
    ; 
        Rest2 = NewRest
    ).
```

Test run:

```
?- index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], List).
List = [0, 2].

?- index_equals_to_element([0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5], List).
List = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5].
```

Comment: Easy to improve (as I show in my reply, posted almost at the same time :-) to make it tail-recursive.

Comment: @PauloMoura yeah, nice tail-recursive solution.

Comment: Thanks. There's another, more subtle, difference between our two versions of the predicate. Using `(=:=)/2` for comparison means that your solution will throw an exception if one of the list elements is not a number while mine will just proceed to the next element. Of course, the problem statement doesn't make clear what would be the preferable behavior.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is:

```
index_equals_to_element(List1, List2) :-
    % assume that list position index starts at 0
    index_equals_to_element(List1, 0, List2).

index_equals_to_element([], _, []).
index_equals_to_element([X| Xs], Index, List2) :-
    NextIndex is Index + 1,
    (   X == Index ->
        List2 = [X| Tail],
        index_equals_to_element(Xs, NextIndex, Tail)
    ;   index_equals_to_element(Xs, NextIndex, List2)
    ).
```

Example call:

```
?-  index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], List).
List = [0, 2].
```

I suggest you study it by using the trace feature of your Prolog system by typing the query:

```
?-  trace, index_equals_to_element([0, 3, 2, 4, 0], List).
```

Step trough the execution until is the predicate definition is clear for you.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are best for learning the nuts and bolts of Prolog. But here's a more concise (but also easier to grok) solution using the higher-order predicate `findall/3` and `nth0/3` from the SWI-Prolog `library(lists)`:

```
elements_equal_to_index(List, Elements) :-
    findall(Index, nth0(Index, List, Index), Elements).
```

**Edit:**

As @Paulo Moura pointed out in a comment, the above answer is only equivalent to the others offered here if all argument are instantiated. I.e., if the above encounters a free variable in the list, I will bind that variable to its index in the list instead of rejecting it as an unsatisfactory element. The addition of a test for strong equality between the index and the list element should make the answer conform:

```
elements_equal_to_index(List, Elements) :-
    findall( Index,
             ( nth0(Index, List, Elem),
               Elem == Index ),
             Elements
           ).
```

Comment: Note that your (nice and concise) solution is only equivalent to the solutions me and Sergey posted when all list arguments are **instantiated**. Of course, that's a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @PauloMoura Thanks for the tip! I edited my post to take your point into account. Cheers.